# How to restrict to a list of query params for a REST api

Tags: rest, jersey, resteasy

I want to restrict to a set of query params for rest Method.

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/query")
    public Response getUsers(
        @QueryParam("from") int from,
        @QueryParam("to") int to,
        @QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy) {

        return Response
           .status(200)
           .entity("getUsers is called, from : " + from + ", to : " + to
            + ", orderBy" + orderBy.toString()).build();

    }

}
```

“users/query?from=100&to=200&orderBy=age&orderBy=name” [WORKS]
“users/query?x=y” [also works and when my query params are set with default values]

i want throw some exceptions based on that.

Comment: You can use bean validation. [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Validation)

Comment: What do you mean by _also works and when my query params are set with default values_? It shouldn't _work_. When running the second query are your parameters filled with default values? When exactly do you want to throw an exception?

Comment: yes in case i have default values set ... i don;t want unsupported query params .. i want to know if these  extra query params can be filtered from jersey layer itself.. or i will have to do it myself in my code..